# sql to add values across rows and down columns

Tags: java, sql, web-applications

I'm porting an excel "database" to a real database application and the customer wants to see familiar spreadsheet views showing data added across rows and summed down columns.  Is this possible with a SQL querys?  Or should the application be performing these aggregate calculations?  I am writing the application in Java and Oracle for persistence.

```
Schema:
    CREATE TABLE CTC_COST_TO_COMPLETE (
    COST_TO_COMPLETE_ID VARCHAR2(24) NOT NULL,
    LINECODE VARCHAR2(16),
    DEPT VARCHAR2(6),
    YEAR VARCHAR2(4),
    SUPERVISOR VARCHAR2(9),
    JAN VARCHAR2(12),
    FEB VARCHAR2(12),
    MAR VARCHAR2(12),
    APR VARCHAR2(12),
    MAY VARCHAR2(12),
    JUN VARCHAR2(12),
    JUL VARCHAR2(12),
    AUG VARCHAR2(12),
    SEP VARCHAR2(12),
    OCT VARCHAR2(12),
    NOV VARCHAR2(12),
    DEC VARCHAR2(12),
             );
```

Each Line code stores the man hour estimates a supervisor needs per month

```
RAW:
id       Linecode     Dept    Year    Supervisor    Jan     Feb     Mar ... Dec
1        ED.312        400    2011      P13341       12      10      15 ...   6
2        GR.544        400    2011      P13341       23       5       1 ...   9
3        WV.132        400    2011      P13341        2       1      18 ...  16



Need out on web page:
  Linecode     Dept    Year    Supervisor    Jan     Feb     Mar ... Dec   Sub Total
  ED.312        400    2011      Rozycki      12      10      15 ...   6         135
  GR.544        400    2011      Rozycki      23       5       1 ...   9          76
  WV.132        400    2011      Rozycki       2       1      18 ...  16          89
 ====================================================================================
                                      Total   37      16      34 ...  31         300
```

Views are a little more complicated than what I am showing.   I may want to summarize totals by linecode for ALL supervisors, for instance.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your database design (schema)?

Comment: I have edited my question to include schema info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best done outside of the database layer.  For what it's worth, you wouldn't be storing it in row/column format as shown anyway (or shouldn't) - in which case the tabulation only happens at the display layer.

Use 2d arrays to store the data while rendering, and sum along the dimensions of the array to get row/column totals.

Comment: are you refering to my db schema when you say not to store in row/column format? In other words my table is not normalized?  I don't see a big deal to have the 12 month fields per record because they hold monthly man hour estimates.

Comment: My queries are not that simple.  I started to investigate Oracle ROLLUP.

Comment: Outside the DB layer - in the Servlet or View?

Comment: @jeff This is a presentation layer problem, so I would use View

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. I did attempt to do it in the view, and it worked great within my Eclipse local environment, but then when I pushed to our development server I got "code too large for try { " error. I was storing the running sums/totals using <c:set within the view. That seemed to be the cause. So now what?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do the subtotals in SQL and didn't want to use something like [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) you could do something like this:

```
select Jan, Feb, Mar, ..., Dec, Jan + Feb + Mar + ... + Dec AS SubTotal
from MyTable

union all

select SUM(Jan), SUM(Feb), SUM(Mar), SUM(Jan + Feb + Mar + ... + Dec)
from MyTable
```